# the $P(\cos X> \sin X)$

Tags: probability, statistics

Let the random variable $X$ have uniform distribution on the interval ($\pi/6, \pi/2$), then the $P(\cos X> \sin X)$

Work: $\cos x> \sin x$ on ($\pi/6, \pi/4$) $\subset $ ($\pi/6, \pi/2$) but after that how to find area? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

$X$ is a uniform distribution on $(\pi/6 , \pi/2)$.

Hence the probability is $\frac{\pi/4-\pi/6}{\pi/2-\pi/6}$.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ibe44e In region  A we have $\cos{x}>\sin{x}$ if i will just calculate area of that region, will that give me required probability? 

$\frac{1}{(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6})}\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(\cos{x}-\sin{x})dx$

Can you point out my mistake?

Comment: Accoding to the formula $P(a < X < b) = \int_a^b f_X(x) \, dx$, here $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6}}$. Hence the right integral is $\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6}} \int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \color{red}1 \, dx$

Comment: I don't understand why it's $1$ Can you please tell me why ?

Comment: the density of continuos uniform distribution over $[a,b]$ is $\frac{\color{blue}1}{b-a}$ over the domain $[a,b]$ right?

Comment: Yes this i know .$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6}}$  I wanna know  how this has $1$ in it  $\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6}} \int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \color{red}1 \, dx$

Comment: $\int_{\frac{\pi}6}^{\frac{\pi}4} f_X(x) \, dx = \int_{\frac{\pi}6}^{\frac{\pi}4} \frac{\color{red}1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6}} \, dx $

Comment: Omg yes. It will a be single line where this  $\cos{x}>\sin{x}$ will happen. Thank you so much i got it.I feel so dumb now .

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $X$ is uniformly distributed over an interval $[a,b]$, and $[c,d]\subseteq [a,b]$, you have practically by definition the equality

$$P(x\in [c,d]) = \frac{d-c}{b-a}$$

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ibe44e In region  A we have $\cos{x}>\sin{x}$ if i will just calculate area of that region, will that give me required probability? 

$\frac{1}{(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6})}\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(\cos{x}-\sin{x})dx$

Can you point out my mistake?